# Populating complex types in a list of a complex type

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a list of a complex type (called 'ClientMessage'). ClientMessage has a type of dictionary called 'MsgText' and a list of a class called 'ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse' over and above a bunch of other, simple, types.

Currently a stored proc returns three datasets. tmpMsgResult is the primary result and tmpDeeplinkResult and tmpMsgTxt are the secondary, which will be used to enrich the final result.

The stored proc executes quickly(sub second). tmpMsgResult returns 26000 rows, tmpDeeplinkResult returns 21000 rows, tmpMsgTxt  returns 63300 rows.

How do I populate 'MsgText' and 'ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse' in the ClientMessage quickly? I have tried a few ways taking anything from 20 seconds to 45 seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ItchyScratchy13
{
    class CMCSimple
    {
        public static List<ClientMessage> ReadClientMessagesSP(string connString, string GCN, bool? messageDeleted, bool? messageArchived)
        {
            List<ClientMessage> results = new List<ClientMessage>();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("cmc.GetCmcMessages", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GCN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GCN;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeletedMsgs", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = messageDeleted;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ArchivedMsgs", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = messageArchived;

                    conn.Open();

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    var tmpMsgResult = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(s => new ClientMessage
                    {
                        MsgID = s.Field<int>("MessageId"),
                        MsgAuditID = s.Field<int>("MessageAuditId"),
                        MsgGUID = s.Field<Guid>("MsgGuid"),
                    }).ToList();

                    var tmpDeeplinkResult = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Select(s => new AdminClientMessageDeeplink
                    {
                        MessageId = s.Field<int>("MessageId"),
                        DeeplinkMask = s.Field<string>("DeeplinkMask"),
                        DeeplinkName = s.Field<string>("DeeplinkName"),
                        DeepLinkValue = s.Field<string>("DeeplinkValue"),
                    }).ToList();

                    var tmpMsgTxt = ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Select(s => new AdminClietnMsgTxt
                    {
                        MessageId = s.Field<int>("MessageId"),
                        MessageTxt = s.Field<string>("MessageText"),
                        RowNumber = int.Parse(s.Field<Int64>("ROW_NUMBER").ToString()),

                    }).ToList();



                    //ATTEMPT 1
                    Parallel.ForEach(tmpMsgResult, item =>
                    {
                        item.DeepLink = tmpDeeplinkResult.Where(wh => wh.MessageId == item.MsgID).Select(s => new ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse
                        {
                            DeeplinkMask = s.DeeplinkMask,
                            DeeplinkName = s.DeeplinkName,
                            DeepLinkValue = s.DeepLinkValue,
                        }).ToList();

                        item.MsgText = tmpMsgTxt.Where(wh => wh.MessageId == item.MsgID).Select(s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.RowNumber, s.MessageTxt)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
                    });

                    //ATTEMPT 2
                    results = tmpMsgResult.Select((x, i) => new ClientMessage
                    {
                        DeepLink = tmpDeeplinkResult.Where(wh => wh.MessageId == x.MsgID).AsParallel().Select(s => new ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse() { DeeplinkMask = s.DeeplinkMask, DeeplinkName = s.DeeplinkName, DeepLinkValue = s.DeepLinkValue }).ToList(),
                        MsgAuditID = x.MsgAuditID,
                        MsgGUID = x.MsgGUID,
                        MsgID = x.MsgID,
                        MsgText = tmpMsgTxt.Where(wh => wh.MessageId == x.MsgID).AsParallel().Select(s => new { s.RowNumber, s.MessageTxt }).ToDictionary(td => td.RowNumber, td => td.MessageTxt)
                    }).ToList();

                    //ATTEMPT 3
                    foreach (var item in tmpMsgResult)
                    {
                        item.DeepLink = tmpDeeplinkResult.Where(wh => wh.MessageId == item.MsgID).Select(s => new ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse
                        {
                            DeeplinkMask = s.DeeplinkMask,
                            DeeplinkName = s.DeeplinkName,
                            DeepLinkValue = s.DeepLinkValue
                        }).ToList();

                        item.MsgText = tmpMsgTxt.Where(wh => wh.MessageId == item.MsgID).Select(s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.RowNumber, s.MessageTxt)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
                    }

                    //ATTEMPT 4, super fast but not correct result set
                    results = (from zxc in tmpMsgResult
                               join vbn in tmpDeeplinkResult
                                 on zxc.MsgID equals vbn.MessageId
                               join asd in tmpMsgTxt
                                   on zxc.MsgID equals asd.MessageId
                               select new ClientMessage
                               {                                   
                                   DeepLink = new List<ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse>() { vbn },                                   
                                   MsgAuditID = zxc.MsgAuditID,                                   
                                   MsgGUID = zxc.MsgGUID,
                                   MsgID = zxc.MsgID,                                   
                                   MsgText = new Dictionary<int, string> { { asd.RowNumber, asd.MessageTxt } }
                               }).ToList();
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

    }

    public class ClientMessage
    {
        public int MsgID { get; set; }
        public int MsgAuditID { get; set; }
        public Guid? MsgGUID { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, string> MsgText { get; set; }
        public List<ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse> DeepLink { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdminClientMessageDeeplink : ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse
    {
        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public int DeeplinkId { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdminClietnMsgTxt
    {
        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public string MessageTxt { get; set; }
        public int RowNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse
    {
        public string DeeplinkName { get; set; }
        public string DeepLinkValue { get; set; }
        public string DeeplinkMask { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Dictionaries instead of Lists? You iterate over the same tmpDeeplinkResult and tmpMsgTxt lists multiple times unnecessarily.

Comment: In your last attempt you can add 
`group new { zxc , vbn , asd } by zxc.MessageId into gr`
and then use it in select. In order to get value of zxc you can do just `gr.First().zxc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `GroupBy` and `Dictionaries` it should be possible to do something along the lines of:

```
....

// It's better to use Dictionary for tmpDeeplinkResult and tmpMsgTxt

var grouppedTmpDeeplinkResult = tmpDeeplinkResult.GroupBy(x => x.MessageId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
var grouppedTmpMsgTxt = tmpDeeplinkResult.GroupBy(x => x.MessageId).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(x => x.RowNumber, x => x.MessageTxt));

foreach (var item in tmpMsgResult)
{
    item.DeepLink = grouppedTmpDeeplinkResult[item.MsgID].Select(s => new ClientMessageDeeplinkResponse
    {
        DeeplinkMask = s.DeeplinkMask,
        DeeplinkName = s.DeeplinkName,
        DeepLinkValue = s.DeepLinkValue
    }).ToList();
    item.MsgText = grouppedTmpMsgTxt[item.MsgID];
}

....
```

Dictionary's lookup such as dict[x] may seem the same as List's but it uses hashset and has `O(1)` complexity whilst `list.Where(...)` has complexity of `O(N)`.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestions shows a reasonable improvement in speed. Almost 4 times quicker.